# Is it possible to send push notifications to Android without building any application?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I don't want to build an application for my web site. However, I want to send push notifications to Android devices. Is this possible?

Comment: How were you envisioning sending these messages? And how were you envisioning collecting and holding the GCM registration IDs of the devices?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I don't know. Can't I collect the IDs over web with the help of Google Chrome or build in application in Android? I can store the IDs in my web server.

Comment: @CommonsWare, is it a must to have an application in order to send push notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have asked this question it wasn't possible. But later Web Notifications have appeared. You can receive a web notification from a web browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Answer (score 8):

The answer to the question is simply NO, you need to register an app to google C2DM server, to be able to send push notification to this device.

Comment: It depends on their requirements. They could use a workaround to receive a notification on the phone.

Comment: Not true. You can services like www.spontit.com to send push notifications.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your requirements. You can use third-party service like Pushed (https://pushed.co/) or Spontit (https://spontit.com, https://api.spontit.com).

Or you can setup the website as a Chrome-app on the phone and then you'll be able to send notifications through Chrome.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en

In both scenarious you'll need to advise your users to install the app on the phone which will subscribe to notifications.

Answer (score 2):

you need REGISTRATION_KEY of particular android device for send push notification to android phone.

Comment: How do I get the `REGISTRATION_KEY` without building an app?

Comment: without building an app. you get API key not RegistrationKey/DeviceToken so for get RegistrationKey you need to follow steps which is below url.                            http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

Physical web is the answer to that. With Eddystone-URL, it is possible to send notifications to phone without app.

Check this,
https://google.github.io/physical-web/